# T-SQL Procedure set a column label (as) dynamically

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sqldependency

Context: I have a c# application which listening an event from table in SQL Server 2012 , I use the SqlDependencyEx for subscribe.

I want to set a label to my column dynamically because the column of my table (tfs table) contains a white space (ex: "Revised Date") and the xml is not correctly generated.

I have added the LTRIM for skip a starting white space but my replace function doesn't work.

The interesting part :

```
SET @select = STUFF((SELECT '', LTRIM(['' + COLUMN_NAME + '']) AS REPLACE('' + COLUMN_NAME + '', '''' '''', '')
                                             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                             WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''{5}'' AND TABLE_CATALOG = ''{0}''
                                             FOR XML PATH ('''')
                                             ), 1, 1, '''')
```

Full code :

```
        /// <summary>
    /// T-SQL script-template which creates notification setup procedure.
    /// {0} - database name.
    /// {1} - setup procedure name.
    /// {2} - service broker configuration statement.
    /// {3} - notification trigger configuration statement.
    /// {4} - notification trigger check statement.
    /// {5} - table name.
    /// {6} - schema name.
    /// </summary>
    private const string SQL_FORMAT_CREATE_INSTALLATION_PROCEDURE = @"
            USE [{0}]
            " + SQL_PERMISSIONS_INFO + @"
            IF OBJECT_ID ('{6}.{1}', 'P') IS NULL
            BEGIN
                EXEC ('
                    CREATE PROCEDURE {6}.{1}
                    AS
                    BEGIN
                        -- Service Broker configuration statement.
                        {2}

                        -- Notification Trigger check statement.
                        {4}

                        -- Notification Trigger configuration statement.
                        DECLARE @triggerStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
                        DECLARE @select NVARCHAR(MAX)
                        DECLARE @sqlInserted NVARCHAR(MAX)
                        DECLARE @sqlDeleted NVARCHAR(MAX)

                        SET @triggerStatement = N''{3}''

                        SET @select = STUFF((SELECT '', LTRIM(['' + COLUMN_NAME + '']) AS REPLACE('' + COLUMN_NAME + '', '''' '''', '')
                                             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                             WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''{5}'' AND TABLE_CATALOG = ''{0}''
                                             FOR XML PATH ('''')
                                             ), 1, 1, '''')
                        SET @sqlInserted = 
                            N''SET @retvalOUT = (SELECT '' + @select + N'' 
                                                 FROM INSERTED 
                                                 FOR XML PATH(''''row''''), ROOT (''''inserted''''))''
                        SET @sqlDeleted = 
                            N''SET @retvalOUT = (SELECT '' + @select + N'' 
                                                 FROM DELETED 
                                                 FOR XML PATH(''''row''''), ROOT (''''deleted''''))''                            
                        SET @triggerStatement = REPLACE(@triggerStatement
                                                 , ''%inserted_select_statement%'', @sqlInserted)
                        SET @triggerStatement = REPLACE(@triggerStatement
                                                 , ''%deleted_select_statement%'', @sqlDeleted)

                        EXEC sp_executeSql @triggerStatement
                    END
                    ')
            END
        ";
```

SQLDependencyEx : https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener/blob/master/ServiceBrokerListener/ServiceBrokerListener.Domain/SqlDependencyEx.cs

Thanks !

EDIT :

```
  LTRIM([PartitionId]) AS REPLACE('PartitionId', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Revised Date]) AS REPLACE('Revised Date', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Not A Field]) AS REPLACE('Not A Field', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Changed Date]) AS REPLACE('Changed Date', ' ', ''), LTRIM([PersonId]) AS REPLACE('PersonId', ' ', ''), LTRIM([AreaID]) AS REPLACE('AreaID', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Rev]) AS REPLACE('Rev', ' ', ''), LTRIM([State]) AS REPLACE('State', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Reason]) AS REPLACE('Reason', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Assigned To]) AS REPLACE('Assigned To', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Created By]) AS REPLACE('Created By', ' ', ''), LTRIM([ID]) AS REPLACE('ID', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Changed Order]) AS REPLACE('Changed Order', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Authorized Date]) AS REPLACE('Authorized Date', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Watermark]) AS REPLACE('Watermark', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Created Date]) AS REPLACE('Created Date', ' ', ''), LTRIM([IterationID]) AS REPLACE('IterationID', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Title]) AS REPLACE('Title', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Changed By]) AS REPLACE('Changed By', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Work Item Type]) AS REPLACE('Work Item Type', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10012]) AS REPLACE('Fld10012', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10002]) AS REPLACE('Fld10002', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10003]) AS REPLACE('Fld10003', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10005]) AS REPLACE('Fld10005', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10008]) AS REPLACE('Fld10008', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10010]) AS REPLACE('Fld10010', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10011]) AS REPLACE('Fld10011', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10009]) AS REPLACE('Fld10009', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10006]) AS REPLACE('Fld10006', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10007]) AS REPLACE('Fld10007', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10004]) AS REPLACE('Fld10004', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10013]) AS REPLACE('Fld10013', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10014]) AS REPLACE('Fld10014', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10016]) AS REPLACE('Fld10016', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10020]) AS REPLACE('Fld10020', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10022]) AS REPLACE('Fld10022', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10015]) AS REPLACE('Fld10015', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10021]) AS REPLACE('Fld10021', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10017]) AS REPLACE('Fld10017', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10018]) AS REPLACE('Fld10018', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10019]) AS REPLACE('Fld10019', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10023]) AS REPLACE('Fld10023', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10024]) AS REPLACE('Fld10024', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10025]) AS REPLACE('Fld10025', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10027]) AS REPLACE('Fld10027', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10028]) AS REPLACE('Fld10028', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10026]) AS REPLACE('Fld10026', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10029]) AS REPLACE('Fld10029', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10032]) AS REPLACE('Fld10032', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10033]) AS REPLACE('Fld10033', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10037]) AS REPLACE('Fld10037', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10038]) AS REPLACE('Fld10038', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10039]) AS REPLACE('Fld10039', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10040]) AS REPLACE('Fld10040', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10041]) AS REPLACE('Fld10041', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10036]) AS REPLACE('Fld10036', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10042]) AS REPLACE('Fld10042', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10043]) AS REPLACE('Fld10043', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10044]) AS REPLACE('Fld10044', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10045]) AS REPLACE('Fld10045', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10047]) AS REPLACE('Fld10047', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10048]) AS REPLACE('Fld10048', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10049]) AS REPLACE('Fld10049', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10052]) AS REPLACE('Fld10052', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10053]) AS REPLACE('Fld10053', ' ', ''), LTRIM([Fld10110]) AS REPLACE('Fld10110', ' ', '')
```

And the result my code :

```
<root>
<inserted>
    <row>1janv  1 9999 12:00AM80juil  1 2016 11:35AM2375595CrééNouveau237523751016&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x1;rO&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;juil  1 2016 11:35AM5156juil  1 2016  9:22AM59Test Query Notification2375Récit utilisateurjuil  1 2016  9:22AMjuil  1 2016  9:22AM1 - Normal2375juil  7 2016 10:00PMJOSEPH Quentin</row>
</inserted>
<deleted>
    <row>1janv  1 9999 12:00AM72juil  1 2016 11:22AM2375594CrééNouveau237523751016&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x1;rG&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;juil  1 2016 11:22AM5155juil  1 2016  9:22AM59Test Query Notification2375Récit utilisateurjuil  1 2016  9:22AMjuil  1 2016  9:22AM1 - Normal2375juil  7 2016 10:00PMJOSEPH Quentin</row>
</deleted>
```

EDIT 2:

The final code :

```
SET @select = STUFF((SELECT '', LTRIM('' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + '') AS '' + QUOTENAME(REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, '' '', ''''))
                                             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                             WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''{5}'' AND TABLE_CATALOG = ''{0}''
                                             FOR XML PATH ('''')
                                             ), 1, 1, '''')
```

Comment: This sort of deeply-nested, triple-quoted code is next to impossible to debug. Try breaking it down to basic levels first.

Comment: Printing the statements will help you debug it much more easily.

Comment: I think the replace failed but i don't know how solve the problem

Comment: The basic construct you're going for (`SELECT X AS <expression>`) isn't syntactically valid. What follows after `AS` must be a column literal. So you're looking at yet another level of quoting to dynamically construct whatever comes after `AS`.

Comment: Hi @JeroenMostert, you suggest me to create a temporary table which store the column and the column replaced ?

Comment: I'm not suggesting anything because this stuff makes my head hurt, I was merely pointing out that queries can't have dynamic column names. Rather than `SELECT X AS <expression>`, you need `SELECT 'SELECT X AS ' + QUOTENAME(<expression>)`, all embedded again of course.

Comment: Thank you @JeroenMostert, it's work great with QUOTENAME !